# Efficient Data Storage For Nucleotides With Common Repeats

Tags: algorithm, binary, data-storage, dna-sequence, computer-science-theory

I'm working on a fun problem regarding finding a more efficient way to store the genome of the human malaria parasite, and I thought it would be useful to get some our your insights!

So here's the background info: suppose we're only using 2 bits to store all 4 nucleotides of the genome (A, C, T, G), but because the genome is still SUPER long, we know it takes up a ton of space. However, we know that 80% of the genome is either A or T - how can we use this knowledge to our advantage to store the genome in a more efficient way?

Right now I'm playing around with a couple ideas:

1. Find some way to encode large strings of A's or large strings of T's - this would require more than 2 bits, but if the strings are especially large, it could reduce size. For example, if '01' was code for 'T', '1101' could be code for '3 T's' (using the normal binary system after the first two bits). This would save us two bits.
2. Simply store A as '0' and T as '1' to reduce the number of bits these letters use.

Anyone else have any good ideas for making this data storage as efficient as possible? I'd love to hear 'em and discuss!

Comment: There has been many works on [lossless compression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lossless_compression) and you could get inpiration from them. They rely either on the statistical properties of elements (Huffman, arith. coding) or on the analysis of sequences (LZW, run-length codes). The basic idea is to code with the smallest length the most frequent  items.

Comment: it all depends on whether you need to access the string _after_ encoding. If you don't, just read [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compression_of_Genomic_Sequencing_Data), otherwise please explain how you plan to access the string

Comment: @AlainMerigot Thanks so much for the link! I've been reviewing Huffman coding for the past few weeks, and that definitely seems like it could be a potential solution here. I'm going to look into it a little more and see what I come up with!

Comment: @WalterTross We aren't concerned with accessing the string after encoding (though in the real world one certainly would be!) I'll take a chance to read through your link and see if I can use the inforamtion to come up with a solution!

Comment: @T.Torline I would strongly recommend that you give a shot at just encoding it, then running it through gzip.  Odds are that you'd have to work surprisingly hard to come up with a custom compression method that is significantly better than that.

Comment: @btilly The hope here is to gain a little intuition behind how a compression method like gzip might work! If I actually had this genome, I would certainly use a pre-built compression method.